# How to pd.json_normalize() in pySpark DF

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I tried doing explod but unable to do it can anyone tell me how to do you explode properly.

df = spark.createDataFrame([row])
df.show()

```
+-----+------------+------------------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|error|fareBenefits|lowestFareProducts|products|    responseMetadata|              slices|                utag|
+-----+------------+------------------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|     |     [FIRST]|           [FIRST]| [FIRST]|{pricedSliceIndex...|[{economyWebSpeci...|{ticket_type -> A...|
+-----+------------+------------------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

now how do i explode slices same way and output should be a df

Answer (score 0):

You can try PySpark for working with structured data.

The below is the code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, ArrayType
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("ExplodeExample").getOrCreate()
data = [
    ("", ["FIRST", "SECOND", "THIRD"], ["A", "B", "C"], ["X", "Y", "Z"])
]
schema = StructType([
    StructField("error", StringType(), True),
    StructField("fareBenefits", ArrayType(StringType()), True),
    StructField("lowestFareProducts", ArrayType(StringType()), True),
    StructField("products", ArrayType(StringType()), True)
])
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=schema)
df.show()
df_exploded_fareBenefits = df.select("*", explode("fareBenefits").alias("exploded_fareBenefits"))
df_exploded_fareBenefits.show()
```

**This is the initial DataFrame** and

[image]

- To perform operations similar to `pd.json_normalize()` in PySpark, you would typically need to write custom code to manually extract and flatten the nested data as shown in the example.
- This process involves explode, select to achieve the desired
  structure.

The code uses the explode function to split the "**fareBenefits**" array column into separate rows while aliasing the new column as "**exploded_fareBenefits.**"

From the above code you can use PySpark for structured data processing and create a Spark DataFrame, define and apply schema, explode an array column to create multiple rows